# Restrict permissions for bot with "subscribe to bot events"

Tags: slack-api

**Situation:**

- our bot is supposed to provide management information to selected users in a slack team
- thus, we want to limit access to the bot to users defined by the admin of the slack team
- we want the bot to be only addressable via a Private channel or a multi-party direct message conversation
- we understand that the bot app itself cannot create such a private channel
- "Default" bot events are im_created, message.channels, message.groups, message.im

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct that we try to restrict access to bot via events?
2. Is it sufficient if we subscribe only to message.groups and message.im?
3. Is it correct that when we don't subscribe to im_created and message.channels, that our bot will not answer to direct messages sent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are technically correct, that by not subscribing to events that are linked to certain conversation types, your bot will not receive messages from those conversations and can therefore obviously not react to it.

However, in my opinion this is not a good approach, because you want your bot to always be able to respond to a user and not appear "dead". At least to tell the user that he is not authorized. Also consider that your bot user can still be invited to all conversation types.

Instead your bot should be subscribed to all relevant events and then react and apply restrictions based on which events he gets.

Access to your bot can be restricted simply by checking if the calling user is authenticated. e.g. the message event always contains the user ID. You can restrict further by checking against the channel ID of the the current request, which will e.g. indicate if its used in public or private channel.

Example message event:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "channel": "C2147483705",
    "user": "U2147483697",
    "text": "Hello world",
    "ts": "1355517523.000005"
}
```

Note that subscribing to events like `message.groups` means that your bot will receive all messages that are sent to those channels, where your bot user is a member of. You bot app then needs to filter through them and pick the right message to react to. If you just want to react to `@botuser`, you may want to consider subscribing only to `app_mention`.

One correction: Although your can not create a new private channel with a bot token, your Slack app will always receive bot a bot token and a user token. With the latter you can create new private channels on behalf of the installing user.

Note that you may also want to consider using [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) for your bot (e.g. `/mgmtbot info`) instead of a bot user / events. You can restrict your response based on user ID and channel of the caller similar to events and the slash command is available to users without having to invite your bot user to a conversation / channel first.

Comment: Thanks! additional question for clarification: I thought that I define what permissions my app needs, the user accepts it and invites the bot to his/her team. how would I check then if a user of that team is authenticated?

Comment: The Slack app Oauth permissions that you need to accept while installing the app to a Slack workspace are global and the same for every user of a team. If you want to differentiate between users, you need to either rely on the the roles from Slack (e.g. admin or owner) or implement your own user management.

Comment: Or you can use private channels to manage access to your bot. So everyone, who is a member of a specific private channel gets access to your bot. With that approach you do not need to implement your own user management. Its how I do it too for my Slack team btw.

Comment: additional request for clarification: could you pls specify how a bot can create a private channel by using a user token? thx

Comment: sure. After installing your Slack app you will get two tokens. A bot token and a user token. With the later you can create new private channel through group.create, assuming that you Slack app has the necessary scope (groups.write) and the user that installed the Slack app has the necessary permissions (those can be restricted to users with admin or owner role).

Comment: Hi Erik. another question about the user management you mentioned. We use Dialogflow as BOT platform and connect it with Slack. However, Dialogflow does not pass the necessary Slack tokens back to us to manage permissions. This basically prevents us from setting up a user management. Any experience with / idea about that?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I'm curious about your use of private channels to manage access to your bot. By default, everyone can invite the bot to a channel be it public or not right? So a user in the workspace can actually invite the bot on his own private channel and issue commands at will. How do you mitigate that?